# MenuItem_Click' is not valid. 'Click' is not an event on 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, datagrid, click

When I try to compile the following WPF DataGrid code, Visual Studio complains that "'MenuItem_Click' is not valid. 'Click' is not an event on 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn'."

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Header Text" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="c1" Binding="{Binding C1}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="c2" Binding="{Binding C2}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="c3" Binding="{Binding C2}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The Click handler is defined on the MenuItem, not on a DataGridTextColumn. Why does having this Click handler break the DataGrid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XAML does not find `MenuItem_Click`, because `<Style>` creates a new XAML namescope (see [WPF XAML Namescopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for an explanation of namescopes). XAML looks for event handler names only within the enclosing namescope.

In order to fix the problem, move the `ContextMenu` to a resource, like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="myContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Header Text" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource myContextMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="c1" Binding="{Binding C1}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="c2" Binding="{Binding C2}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="c3" Binding="{Binding C2}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```